# iOS Today Widgets (old widgets) disappear after EVERY app update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widget, widgetkit

We had "Today widgets" that worked perfect for a long time. After introducing the new Widgets Extension we added a Widgets Bundle to our app. Now after every app update the old widgets disappear from "Today view" and can be bring back ONLY by rebooting the iPhone.

Sometime when they disappear, in today view appears the first widget from the Widgets Bundle. I've tested other apps too and it happens every time on apps that support old and new widgets (Xiaomi Home app for example).

Does anyone have a clue how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I have rаised a ticket to the Apple Developer Technical Support and I got the following response unfortunately:

> Hi Stefan,
>
> Today extensions are no longer supported on iOS. You should migrate to
> use Widgets exclusively as the experience you are seeing with today
> extensions has no fix or workaround.
>
> Once a Widget target is added to your project they will take precedent
> over today extensions and as we mentioned at WWDC, they are an
> intended replacement, so you will see the system suppress the today
> extensions. I would argue thats seeing the today extensions at all is
> actually a bug.

It's a shame that Apple want us to migrate to the useless Widgets that are not even close to the Today extensions functionality.
It might help if everyone affected create a ticket.